# Expected number of sum vs sum of expected number (basic)

Tags: probability

I have read that $E[\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{I_k}} ] = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {E[{I_k}]}$ What does each side of the equation mean (how is it called?) and how to calculate it?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This equality does not hold in general. Can you include the definition of the $I_k$?

Comment: yes, I added it

Comment: $E[X]$ is the expected value of the random variable $X$.  Now... on the left, notice that the sum of random variables is again a random variable.  On the right it is the sum of the respective expected values of each of the $I_k$ individually.  The property you describe is called the "Linearity of expectation."  As carmichael561 alludes, there are some conditions for the infinite version to work correctly, but the finite version is true in general.

Answer (score 0):

Since $I_k$ are nonnegative, this is an automatic consequence of Tonelli's theorem.

Were you to replace the $I_k$ with general functions $f_k$, you'd need to use the Fubini theorem where you need to check integrability first.